# gamepad for node.js serialport

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, gamepad-api, node-serialport

I would like to use my gamepad with [node.js serialport](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport) - to control robots basically.

I do not want to reinvent the wheel, so would it be possible to port the [pygames joystick](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html) to javascript - based on Chris Williams serialport?

Anyone thought about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that someone has actually started [such a project](https://npmjs.org/package/node-pad).

Creationix (*AKA Tim Caswell*) also has something that he has worked on and [blogged about](http://nodebits.org/linux-joystick).